# Backing up a custom VirtualBox image before upgrading disk

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I want to upgrade my HDD to an SSD.  Before I do that, I was wondering if I have an Ubuntu VirtualBox image with tools, etc. and files that I have been using. Before I install the SSD could I export the image to a USB stick or something so that when I install the new SSD I have the image as is? I don't lose anything.

Comment: Are you speaking about your actual whole system or only about a single virtual machine that is working below your system? Because if it is the second case, you can do easily copying the directory with the `.vbox` and `.vdi` files (in case of  problem fixing the UUID of the disk after.  There was even a procedure to export a (stopped) virtual machine in a single file that you can import later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of potential scenarios here, but the short answer is yes.  Shut down the virtual and you can move its image anywhere you need to.  Once you change the drives you can move the image back over and set it up in VirtualBox.